# Basic Scala for loop Issue

Tags: scala

I am trying to learn scala, here I am using basic for loop, but I am getting errors while compiling.

```
object App {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    for (i <- 1 to 10; i % 2 == 0)
      Console.println("Counting " + i)

  }
}
```

Errors while compiling :

```
fortest.scala:5: error: '<-' expected but ')' found.

    for (i <- 1 to 10; i % 2 == 0)
                                 ^
fortest.scala:7: error: illegal start of simple expression

  }
  ^

two errors found
```

I am using scala version 2.9.1

Any idea what is the problem..............?

Answer (score 8):

```
for (i <- 1 to 10 if i % 2 == 0)
  println("Counting " + i)
```

Answer (score 7):

Scala is not Java, thus you cannot use a regular Java syntax. Instead you have to do:

```
for{
    i <- 1 to 10
    if(i % 2 == 0)
}{println("Counting " + i)}
```

or with `;` delimeters, inside the `(`,`)` parentheses:

```
for(i <- 1 to 10;if(i % 2 == 0)){
    println("Counting " + i)
}
```

Also, note that Scala's for expressions, have some pretty nifty capabilities.
you can use a for expression with multiple "loop iterators" and conditions.

For instance, instead of writing:

```
for(i <- 1 to n; if(someCondition(i)){
    for(j <- 1 to m; if(otherCondition(j)){
         //Do something
    }
}
```

You can simply write:

```
for{
    i <- 1 to n
    if(someCondition(i))
    j <- 1 to m
    if(otherCondition(j))
}{
    //Do something
}
```

**SIDE NOTE:**
When you extend `App` (there's a trait of that name in `Predef`), you don't need to define a main method. You can simply write your code between the curly braces of `object`:

```
object MyClazz extends App {
    for(i <- 1 to 10;if(i % 2 == 0)){
        println("Counting " + i)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what the basic concept behind scala, which prevents multiple conditions in a for loop?

Comment: you can invoke as many conditions as you want. just add more `if` lines... (i'll edit my answer to include more info on that)

Comment: you can skip semicolon between generator and if-guard: `for (i <- 1 to 10 if i % 2 == 0) println(i)`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the "by" method of the [Range](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range.html) class to count by 2

```
object App {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for (i <- 2 to 10 by 2)
      Console.println("Counting " + i)
  }
}
```

Or, like others have already stated you can fix your loop by doing

```
object App {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    for {
         i <- 1 to 10
         if i % 2 == 0
        }
      Console.println("Counting " + i)
  }
}
```

Or another way:

```
object App {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val evenNumbers = for {
         i <- 1 to 10
         if i % 2 == 0
        } yield i
    Console.println(evenNumbers.mkString("\n"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The modulo 2 condition can be moved to an if clause.

```
object App {    
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    for (i <- 1 to 10)
      if(i % 2 == 0)
      Console.println("Counting " + i)

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simply example;

```
 for (i <- List(1, 2, 3) if i < 2) println(i)
```

The best way to exam your code is to use scala shell.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying to use for-loop + iterator gaurd. Please find below syntax

```
for ( i <- 1 to 10 if (i%2==0) ) yield i
```

Comment: I don't think that your answer, being the 7th on the topic, adds much to this thread.